# Can I Install Laravel 4 package without using Composer?

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php

I want to install intervention/image package on my web server i had installed on my localhost , and i want to install it on my web server , **Can I Install Laravel 4 package without using Composer?** because i don't have acces to use command prompt on my web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you installing Laravel and the other dependencies already?

Just install it locally like normal then copy your vendor directory along with the rest of your project to your host.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running PHP on a shared host without composer you still have some options left:

- [Install composer on the server](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#locally) in the same folder as your project,
- Upload composer.phar to your server,
- Change your hosting provider (try [fortrabbit](https://fortrabbit.com)),
- Upload your vendor folder from your local computer to your server. (Last resort)

Answer (score 0):

it's possible for you to just upload your vendor directory with ftp, but I wouldn't advise it to you.

Couple of reasons:

- You don't want to upload your dev-dependencies, so you would have to handpick which folder to upload - everytime you want to update your dependencies
- Uploading over ftp is **very slow**, so that might take a long time
- You don't get the latest versions of the dependencies (which could resolve some security issues)
- You wouldn't get any warning if some package isn't compatible with your environment.

I suggest you to use a host that gives you CLI, or even better that can directly run composer when you push up your files, as hannesvdvreken said, [fortrabbit](https://fortrabbit.com/) (Disclosure: i work there).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can download it via [LaraPack](http://fian.my.id/larapack/). It provide you ready-to-use Laravel instalation, so you don't have install it with Composer. It also gets weekly update.